# Running SonarQube Scanner on a Jenkins remote slave

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a Docker container running Jenkins (2.150.1) and another Docker container running SonarQube (7.4). Jenkins is using the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) plugin and the scanning is done on the Jenkins container. The `Jenkinsfile` for the project looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'building...'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo 'testing...'
        withSonarQubeEnv ('SonarQube') {
          sh '/var/jenkins_home/sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner'
        }
        echo 'really finished testing2'
      }
    }
    stage("Quality Gate") {
        steps {
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
              waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deployment') {
      steps {
        echo 'deploying...'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get the scanning to work as part of a Jenkins pipeline job, I manually installed `sonar-scanner` on the Jenkins container by downloading the zip file and unzipping it to: `/var/jenkins_home/sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux`

This is working well, but I want to improve it by:

1. **taking out the harcoded path to `sonar-scanner` from my `Jenkinsfile`**
2. **specify a non local location of `sonar-scanner` because I now need to run the scan on another VM/container instead of on the Jenkins container**

I tried using Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > SonarQube Scanner and updated my `Jenkinsfile` to use `SONAR_RUNNER_HOME` instead of the hard coded path, but that didn't work and I got an error that `sonar-scanner` can't be found.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > SonarQube Scanner check `install automatically`.

Then go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System and add the following
[image]

The Name should be the same as the parameter in the line in your Jenkinsfile: `withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube')`